# How to make text appear on Text Widget using .insert

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget

[This is what my gui looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNH6Q.jpg)

This is my program code:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.resizable(0, 0)

def main_process(directory, reference, dialog):


    os.chdir(directory)
    SAP = openpyxl.load_workbook(reference)
    worksheet_SAP = SAP.worksheets[0] 
    total_rows_SAP = worksheet_SAP.max_row
    total_columns_SAP = worksheet_SAP.max_column
    Employees_SAP = []
    SAP_employees_working_dates = {}
    SAP_employees_working_days = {}
    for row in range(2, total_rows_SAP + 1):
        working_days = 0
        dates = []
        employees_SAP = worksheet_SAP.cell(row=row, column=2).value
        Employees_SAP.append(employees_SAP)
        if employees_SAP not in SAP_employees_working_dates:
            SAP_employees_working_dates[employees_SAP] = dates
        for days in range(3, total_columns_SAP + 1):
            workdays_color = PatternFill(fgColor='00000000')
            if worksheet_SAP.cell(row=row, column=days).fill == workdays_color:
                if worksheet_SAP.cell(row=row, column=days).value == "":
                    working_days += 1
                    date_SAP = worksheet_SAP.cell(row=1, column=days).value
                    if len(date_SAP) == 1:
                        date_SAP = "0" + date_SAP
                    dates.append(date_SAP + "/" + "month" + "/" + "year")
        if employees_SAP not in SAP_employees_working_days:
            SAP_employees_working_days[employees_SAP] = working_days
    Employees_SAP.sort()

""" I want to ask on this section """

    while True:
        dialog.insert(tkinter.INSERT, ("SAP File Total Rows : ", total_rows_SAP))
        dialog.insert(tkinter.INSERT, ("SAP File Total Columns :", total_columns_SAP))
        Ask = input("Please Check!\nContinue ? (Y/N)")
        if Ask == "Y" or "y":
            break
dialog_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Dialog Box :")

dialog_label.pack()

dialog_box = tkinter.Text(root, height=4, width=50, bd=5)

dialog_box.pack()

automate_button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Automate This Shit!", bg="yellow", fg="red",
                                 command=lambda: main_process(directory_entry.get(),
                                                              reference_entry.get(),
                                                              dialog_box))
```

How to make dialog.insert on while loop appear on the Text Widget ?

Comment: add `dialog.update_idletasks()` after those `insert(...)`.

Comment: thanks man, but it doesnt work